# How do I access phpMyAdmin on localhost with NginX

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 16.10 (Mate), which I use as a local server just for testing websites that I develop. I recently switched from Apache2 to NginX. I have successfully set up NginX so that all my PHP based sites are running, and I get the output of `phpinfo()`, so I have PHP working.

The instructions I've found for getting phpMyAdmin to work with NginX seemed pretty simple:

1. `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /usr/share/nginx/html/`
2. `sudo service nginx restart`
3. clear the browser cache
4. Open phpMyAdmin in the browser at `localhost/phpmyadmin`

I did all those steps, but I get a 404 not found error. I've tried moving the symlink to phpMyAdmin to different places, such as `/var/www`, which is where my other websites are, but it hasn't helped. It seems no matter where I put phpMyAdmin, it won't open.

**What is the correct way to set up phpMyAdmin so that I can open it on my local NginX server?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. While installing `phpmyadmin`, select `apache2` and install it, it copies the necessary files.
2. Nginx uses `/var/www/html/` as default web server root. So use `ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html`.
3. If you changed web server root, instead of `/var/www/html`, use `your path` and make sure you set the right permissions.
4. Open your browser and open `localhost/phpmyadmin`, you should open `phpMyAdmin`.

Comment: As an additional note, after correcting the symlink location, I also had to make sure the file `/ett/nginx/sites-available/default` had the correct PHP configuration, as figured out in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41520175/184108).

Comment: yes, thank you for completing the answer @Questioner

Answer (score 2):

In Apache2 the symlink would work because of the Apache2 alias module.
In Nginx things work different.
One way to solve this could be to create a new vhost for Nginx.
Here is the relevant part, changing the root, and adding the index.php :

---

```
    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

---

Another solution is to read more about aliases with Nginx.
Here is a quick search result :

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias